# npm install in laravel 7.0

Tags: node.js, laravel

While installing npm for my projects of `laravel 7.1` I have got an error

```
hp@LAPTOP-KKGMLCO3 MINGW64 /c/xampp/htdocs/Laravel/e-commerce
$ npm install




audited 17608 packages in 11.022s

35 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities'''
```

Comment: Welcome - that doesn't look like an error to me - can you elaborate on what you think the error is?

Answer (score 1):

That is not an error. Everything installed just fine according to that.